# Ubuntu 13.10 on Asus EEE PC - Possible Issues?

Tags: 13.10, eeepc

I'm looking to play around with Ubuntu 13.10 on my Asus EEE PC 1101 HA with 2 GB Ram (Upgraded at purchase) via a Live USB or Bootable USB drive and I am wondering if anyone knew of any issues that it might cause with Windows XP. I ran the 64-bit version in the same way on a 32-bit machine and then when I booted the PC again normally and Windows wanted to run a system restore on the machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used Ubuntu on my Asus EEE PC (it's the 1005HA model from 2010, came with Win7 Starter) since v10.04, upgraded every release.

It runs fine! It became more with recent versions, and so I recently switched from the default Unity desktop manager to Gnome Fallback which works perfectly well.

Some more intensive applications run slow or just make the fan go nuts but it's a really low power machine, so it's not meant to run loads of applications at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu 13.10 on a Asus eeepc 1000he (also upgraded to 2gb) and everything works great. It can be a little slow, but never a show stopper (for me). I dual boot with Windows XP and there's no trouble.

The important thing to watch out for is to make sure that when you're installing it, is to not move the Windows partition so that it can still be found when booting. If you're not installing and just running from a live CD/USB, you shouldn't have any trouble.

It's also important to use the 32 bit version of Ubuntu on a 32 bit machine.